# Show selectInput in rshiny based on condition (conditionalPanel)

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I want to create an app that allows you to select one variable based on a condition.
So I have create a switchInput with conditions Yes, and No, and as you can see, a stratify SelectInput should appear in case Yes is marked.

However, no new SelectInput is displayed:

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)



not_sel <- "Not Selected"


# User interface

ui <- navbarPage(
  main_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "",
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      switchInput(
        inputId = "Id013",
        onLabel = "Yes",
        offLabel = "No"
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "Id013 == 'Yes'", selectInput("Stratify", "Stratify", choices = c(not_sel)), #uiOutput("factor"),
      ),
      actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plot",
          br(),
          plotOutput("sel_graph")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)




# Server

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data. We allow the user to input the data that they want 
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I understand, based on the conditionalPanel function:

`Creates a panel that is visible or not, depending on the value of a JavaScript expression. The JS expression is evaluated once at startup and whenever Shiny detects a relevant change in input/output.`

That the change on the switchInput value should be enough to generate this changes in the UI interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the docs of `conditionalPanel()`:

> For example, if you have an input with an id of foo, then you can use input.foo to read its value.

So you need to use `input.Id013` instead of `Id013` in the condition. Also, even if the labels of the switch are "Yes" or "No", it returns a value TRUE/FALSE (which are written "true" or "false" in Javascript). So the condition you need to use is:

```r
condition = "input.Id013 == true"
```